# Найти все элементы по className в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как в react можно получить элемент с одинаковым идентификатором? И чтобы на каждого можно было навесить событие onload

```
<div className="parallax-js-content" ref={sceneEl}>
      <img src="./img/home_page/leaf_1.png" alt="Leaf" className="--i-1 preload" data-depth="0.3" />
      <img src="./img/home_page/leaf_2.png" alt="Leaf" className="--i-2 preload" data-depth="-0.7" />
      <img src="./img/home_page/leaf_3.png" alt="Leaf" className="--i-3 preload" data-depth="0.65" />
      <img src="./img/home_page/leaf_4.png" alt="Leaf" className="--i-4 preload" data-depth="0.15" />
      <img src="./img/home_page/leaf_5.png" alt="Leaf" className="--i-5 preload" data-depth="-0.45" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Поясните, что вы хотите сделать? как минимум, рендер img можно вынести в отдельный компонент

Comment: Для прелоадера сайта. Мне нужно достать все картинки и на нах событие onload повесить, а дальше вычисление.

Comment: Какие возникли сложности? Ваш код показывает множественный рендер картинок, но нет ни одного события

Comment: Об этом я не подумал. Помогло! Спасибо.